# Unable to load node.js package

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

I have a node.js project where I'm trying to load and parse .xml files. In an attempt to do this, I was going to rely on the DOM Parser via the following command:

```
npm install xmldom
```

The package was successfully installed. However, when I attempt to execute my code via mocha, I get an error that says: "Error: Cannot find module 'xmldom'". My code works fine until I add the following line at the top of my code:

```
var dom = require('xmldom');
```

If I comment out the line, my code works. But, if I remove the commments, to make the code active, I get the error again. I haven't written anything to actually parse the xml file yet. I'm just trying to import the dom parser at this point.

I also tried loading the xmldom package globally with the following command:

```
npm install -g xmldom
```

That did not solve my problem either. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you installed other packages with NPM and had them work?

Comment: yes. I have successfully installed other node packages. When I run npm list, I can clearly see a number of packages. I can even see xmldom in the list.

Comment: OS and version information?

Comment: Relative to your application's .js file, is the module installed in `node_modules/xmldom`? i.e. did you run npm install xmldom in the folder where your app.js file is?

Comment: If you create a new file `test-dom.js` and put only the one line `var dom = require('xmldom')` in it, does it have the same error?

Comment: @Plato: Shouldn't matter if he installed with -g.  Second comment, worth a shot!

Comment: OS: Windows 7 Profession. I did install the module in the folder where my app.js file is. Just to make sure I'm running the file correctly, how do you run it? I'm currently calling the file through a unit test via the command line (mocha mytests.js)

Comment: It seems like I only get this error when the file gets executed via mocha. If I do 'app.js' it works fine. However, if I do mocha app.tests.js, I get the error mentioned above. If I comment out the offending line, the tests work just fine.

Comment: Try navigating to the folder where mocha resides, probably `~/your_project/node_modules/mocha/`. Do `npm list` and see if it has `xmldom` and what version. If necessary execute `npm install xmldom` while in `mocha/`. Other than that, it's probably some problem with how you set up mocha? I have minimal experience with mocha so I will leave it at that, good luck :D

Comment: @plato - I did everything you mentioned and everything looks fine. However, its still not working :( Thank you for trying though.

Comment: OH i have an idea! Perhaps wherever the mocha binary is being from for (check with `$ which mocha`) doesn't know where to look for `xmldom`. Try instead running the locally installed binary: `$ ~/your_project/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha ~/your_project/mytests.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog post explaining what to look for when you get a [Cannot find module 'xmldom'](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/node-cannot-find-module-xmldom) error.